# Render value inside the another value in HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In html am rendering some value in the and passing it as a input to a component like
below

```
    <test-component
    [title]= "data?.Kevin?.title"
    </test-component>

Please be noted data?.Kevin?.title will give the title name.How ever, in the above, I want to render the name a bit dynamically like below

    <test-component

    [title]= "data?.{{name}}?.title"

    </test-component>

{{name}} should render kevin  and the tile value needs to be passed to the component.

Here the name is not being rendered correctly.

Any help is highly appreciated.
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is pretty simple: `[title]= "data?.[name]?.title"`
the equivalent of the first example would be: `[title]= "data?.["Kevin"]?.title"`

read more on https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp see "Accessing Object Properties"

Comment: HI @Zerotwelve thanks for the response. But unfortunately it didn't work.
   <div *ngFor="let b of testaccount; let index = index">
     <test-component

    [title]= "data?.[["b.name"]]?.title"

    </test-component>

   <div>

Comment: you are doing it wrong. correct should be:  [title]= "data?.[b.name]?.title"